# Reverse tunneling in RaspberryPI and cloud server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have a Raspberry Pi and and i have done reverse tunneling with an AWS instance. I ran the following command below on my Raspberry Pi.

```
ssh -N -R 1234:localhost:22 username@instance_IP
```

and on my Linux instance i am able to ssh using..

```
ssh -l user_pi -p 1234 localhost
```

but i am not able to ssh directly into my PI instead i first have to login to AWS and then into my PI..

how can i login to my PI directly using tunneling?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in case of direct remote connecting you need to allow Tcp Forwarding

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```